# adding every choice of Spinner to the textview

Tags: android, spinner

I want to create a Spinner with multiple choice, and every one that chooses, must add to the spinner box.my spinner has a dropDown List.pictures below will describe what I want to create:

[image: text 1 is selected]

[image: text 1 and text 2 are selected]

[image: text 1 and 2 and 3 are selected]

how can I create this Spinner???

Comment: dont do that, what if you select 100 items? would you like to see all of them in several lines on your screen?

Comment: @pskink I want to limit the selection to three Items only!

Answer (score 2):

try this
you can use  **[TextView.append()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html?hl=es#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)** method.

> Convenience method to append the specified text slice to the TextView's display buffer, upgrading it to EDITABLE if it was not already editable.

**sample code**

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        String s=destspin1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        textView.append(s);

      /* or try this
       String str=textView.getText().toString().trim();
       textView.setText(str+s);*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Comment: I didn't fully understand your solution! tvSchool is the TextView for the Spinner?? I tried it, but didn't work so far,can you explain more?

Comment: @AzinNilchi  replace **tvSchool** with your **Textview**

Comment: I tried that,to put the spinner text view for using append that you said, but it will also crash! with this error :
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.append(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1):

**I have create a full code for you just apply**

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_test_code"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ncrypted.thumbpin.TestCode">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="dsasas"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestCode extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner;
    TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_code);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, new String[]{"String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", "String 5"});
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                String s = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                textView.append(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }

        });

    }
}
```

> **NOTE:** if you want to add particular item at only once than you should have to use ArrayList to store selected items in to array list
>   and loop the array and check the item is already added or not

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. I don't want a separate textView to show these selection! I want to show Spinner selection in Spinner Itself! like images that I've shown